# Symfony2 Unit Testing Forms with constraints

Tags: php, forms, unit-testing, symfony

I've got a form which isn't connected to a entity but does have constraints like mentioned in here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation

> ContactBundle\Tests\Form\Type\TestedTypeTest::testSubmitValidData
>   Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\InvalidOptionsException: The option "constraints" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "inherit_data", "label", "label_attr", "mapped", "max_length", "method", "pattern", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "read_only", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "virtual"

Here is part of the form:

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{

/**
 * Build the form
 * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder BuilderInterface
 * @param array $aOption Array of options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $aOption)
{
    ///..
    $builder->add('name', 'text', array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(array('min' => 3)),
                ),
            ))
            ->add('address', 'textarea', array(
                'required' => false
            ))
            //..
            ;
    //..
```

Here is the unit test

```
class TestedTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{

public function testSubmitValidData()
{
    $formData = array(
        'name' => 'Test Name',
        'address' => '',
    );
    $type = new ContactType();
    $form = $this->factory->create($type, $formData);
    $form->submit($formData);

    $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());

    $view = $form->createView();
    $children = $view->children;

    foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
        $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
    }
}
}
```

I'm guessing that this is a problem with the test instead of the form as the form works as expected. I'm not sure what I should change.
Any help or advice would be handy

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>I think the problem is that you also pass the formData to the factory's create method.</strike>

It should be fine to just pass the form data via `$form->submit($formData)` like you already have in your code

More docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html

**EDIT:**

Well it seems you have to add the validator/constaint extensions to the factory object in your test setup like stated here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html#adding-custom-extensions

Comment: Yeah I did try that: $type = new ContactType(); $form = $this->factory->create($type); but its still the same issue. According to the docs the second param of create could be a object, array or nothing. public function create($type = 'form', $data = null, array $options = array());  Api docs for FormFactoryInterface: http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactoryInterface.html

Comment: Which line is causing the execption? (And the other arguments of create() are finally passed as second parameter in your FormType's buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $aOption))

Comment: From the stack trace: symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolver.php:255
symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolver.php:219
symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ResolvedFormType.php:109
symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php:87
symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php:106
symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php:268
symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php:216
symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php:39
/Tests/Form/Type/ContactTypeTest.php:34

Comment: Sorry its: $form = $this->factory->create($type);

Comment: I updated my answer... you have to add some setup stuff to get constraints supported by the test framework...

Answer (score 5):

Yes Rob was right I needed to add validator/constraint extensions. Like so:

```
 class TestedTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
 {

  protected function setUp()
  {
    parent::setUp();

    $validator = $this->getMock('\Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface');
    $validator->method('validate')->will($this->returnValue(new ConstraintViolationList()));
    $formTypeExtension = new FormTypeValidatorExtension($validator);
    $coreExtension = new CoreExtension();

    $this->factory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
            ->addExtensions($this->getExtensions())
            ->addExtension($coreExtension)
            ->addTypeExtension($formTypeExtension)
            ->getFormFactory();
}
//..
```

Comment: Doesn't this just stub out the constraints? So it's hard to test if the data submitted passes or fails the constraints?

Comment: Indeed, it looks like Victor S is correct. I will allow you to complete the test, but it will not test the constraints. I created a testSubmitInvalidData method with invalid input, but $form->isValid() will always return true. Close, but no cigar.

Comment: Your ConstraintViolationList is empty, your form is always valid

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to override the TypeTestCase::getExtensions() method

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\CoreExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\IdentityTranslator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidatorFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Factory\MetadataFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Tests\Fixtures\FakeMetadataFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator;

....

   public function getExtensions()
    {
        $extensions = parent::getExtensions();
        $metadataFactory = new FakeMetadataFactory();
        $metadataFactory->addMetadata(new ClassMetadata(  Form::class));
        $validator = $this->createValidator($metadataFactory);

        $extensions[] = new CoreExtension();
        $extensions[] = new ValidatorExtension($validator);

        return $extensions;
    }
```

add the method createValidator() in your test class :

```
    protected function createValidator(MetadataFactoryInterface $metadataFactory, array $objectInitializers = array())
    {
        $translator = new IdentityTranslator();
        $translator->setLocale('en');
        $contextFactory = new ExecutionContextFactory($translator);
        $validatorFactory = new ConstraintValidatorFactory();
        return new RecursiveValidator($contextFactory, $metadataFactory, $validatorFactory, $objectInitializers);
    }
```

No need to override TypeTestCase::getTypeExtensions() because ValidatorExtension class already has a loadTypeExtensions() method.

Then, your test method can be like this :

```
public function testSubmitValidData()
{
    $formData = array(
        'name' => 'Test Name',
        'address' => '',
    );
    $form = $this->factory->create(ContactType::class);
    $form->submit($formData);
    $this->assertTrue($form->isValid());
    $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());

    $view = $form->createView();
    $children = $view->children;

    foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
        $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
    }
}
```

You can test invalid data :

```
public function testSubmitInvalidValidData()
{
    $formData = array(
        'name' => 'T',
    );
    $form = $this->factory->create(ContactType::class);
    $form->submit($formData);
    $this->assertFalse($form->isValid());
    $this->assertFalse($view->children['name']->vars['valid']);

}
```

sources :

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html#adding-custom-extensions
- https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/master/Tests/Validator/RecursiveValidatorTest.php#L25

Answer (score 4):

This problem can still occurs with Symfony 4.4 but it is easy to solve.

The `ValidatorExtensionTrait` must be added to the class that runs the test.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class TestedTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    use \Symfony\Component\Form\Test\Traits\ValidatorExtensionTrait;

    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $formData = [...];
        $type = new ContactType();
        $form = $this->factory->create($type, $formData);
    }
}
```

The trait takes care of adding the extension required to make the "constraints" option available.