# Unit testing custom Symfony Form Types

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, symfony-forms

I want to unit test the validation on a custom `FormTypeInterface`.

I have a custom Form Type set up like this:

```
class HiddenFieldType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text', [
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'hiddenfield-invalid'
                ])
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hiddenfield';
    }
}
```

I want to test that the constraint holds by instantiating the form object.  From the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html), I have come up with this:

```
public function testValidation()
{
    $formData = [
        'name' => null // blank value
    ];

    $hiddenFieldType = new HiddenFieldType();
    $form = $this->factory->create($hiddenFieldType);

    // submit the data to the form directly
    $form->submit($formData);

    var_dump($form->isValid()); die;
}

// factory is set up as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/27035802/614523
protected function setUp()
{

    parent::setUp();
    $validator = $this->getMock('\Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface');
    $validator->method('validate')->will($this->returnValue(new ConstraintViolationList()));
    $formTypeExtension = new FormTypeValidatorExtension($validator);

    $this->factory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
        ->addExtensions($this->getExtensions())
        ->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension())
        ->addTypeExtension($formTypeExtension)
        ->getFormFactory();
}
```

My current understanding tells me that `$form->isValid()` should return `false` here (this is how it is used in the controller and in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#handling-form-submissions), but `$form->isValid()` always returns `true` as long as `$formData['name']` contains a string.

I have also tried passing the data using a `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` object:

```
public function testValidation($userInput, $isValid)
{
    $formData = [
        'name' => 'asdasd'
    ];

    $hiddenFieldType = new HiddenFieldType();
    $form = $this->factory->create($hiddenFieldType);

    // submit the data to the form using the request object
    $request = new Request($getParams = [], $postParams = $formData);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    var_dump($form->isValid()); die;
}
```

When I do this `$form->isValid()` always returns false, where I would expect it to be `true` whenever `$formData['name']` is not null and not an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?